# "Request timed out" asp.net error in web application after server migration to Azure

Tags: azure, asp.net, cloud, web-applications

My company has migrated all of our on-prem servers to Azure. We are in the process of functional testing our application. So far, we have found no errors save for one. Whenever we click on a button on the website, the page hangs for about five minutes before redirecting to an error page. We are unable to load the website again until all our browsers are completely closed out and relaunched.

After we log back on, we are able to see that the website on the backend did everything it was supposed to do, but for some reason.... when trying to process the next page to load, it failed.
Everything else in our application works without any timeout. We don't suspect that it's firewall or permissions related because other areas in our application can access the servers without any issue.

We've looked at adjusting timeouts, but all of the timeout settings in our web config files are set to 30 minutes, and our website times out at just 5.

We don't think the issue is code related because it's a straight lift-and-shift from on-prem to Azure. On-prem works, so there's no reason why it shouldn't work in Azure. Nothing has been changed in the code.

Assuming that our networking, firewall, timeouts, and code are all correctly configured, what else could cause our website to hang when it loads a specific page, and then fail with a timeout exception?